# Many Bridge Networks on startup / boot my ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, networking, docker, bridge

When I start ubuntu 18.04, there are MANY Bridge Networks in my ifconfig. I can't connect some networks, (not cabled nor wifi) until I delete some of them.

After delete them, systems works perfectly.

Content of /etc/network/interfaces:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

ifconfig:

```
br-01850822aefc: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.31.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.31.255.255
        ether 02:42:ae:cc:ae:43  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br-0533d7f1a7c4: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 02:42:8d:07:31:2d  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br-0665bdac5306: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 02:42:05:94:7a:aa  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br-0d1d976daa10: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 02:42:6e:fa:e9:f7  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br-1051032a9708: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 02:42:f4:1b:2f:47  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br-14c5799fe1b2: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.24.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.24.255.255
        ether 02:42:34:ce:d1:9d  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br-29193068b7be: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 02:42:37:9b:78:43  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br-356baf420a29: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 02:42:61:f9:f8:ee  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br-37286cdaa43d: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 02:42:e4:9f:d6:39  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br-4379136c3972: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.30.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.30.255.255
        ether 02:42:13:cd:2f:4f  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br-4753952f062a: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.28.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.28.255.255
        ether 02:42:96:2c:70:cc  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br-48f23f7b8ad4: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.25.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.25.255.255
        ether 02:42:a9:c9:9c:e4  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br-4ace4c5ba371: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.48.1  netmask 255.255.240.0  broadcast 192.168.63.255
        ether 02:42:2b:ff:97:e2  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br-4c848250e12d: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.20.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.20.255.255
        ether 02:42:29:2f:c6:35  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br-513c950dbdd1: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.32.1  netmask 255.255.240.0  broadcast 192.168.47.255
        ether 02:42:be:87:08:b6  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br-55b37644da9c: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 02:42:68:92:d5:03  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br-599a0a66bbc9: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 02:42:af:77:9b:d8  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br-59b5648d5af6: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 02:42:b4:cc:ba:a4  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br-887511af4293: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.21.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.21.255.255
        ether 02:42:dc:a9:d9:af  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br-89d49e2f2224: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 02:42:b1:75:4e:50  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br-8bec26608e85: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 02:42:69:b7:88:6c  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br-92a88a91f4b0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.29.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.29.255.255
        ether 02:42:22:39:8a:ae  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br-98b4c7a75e2e: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 02:42:a7:0f:4e:c0  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br-a25c53ab3ce9: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.22.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.22.255.255
        ether 02:42:5c:a0:f7:8a  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br-b01a537efc09: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 02:42:9b:c0:4e:3d  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br-bb41b5e452fb: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 02:42:16:a7:18:48  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br-ccc1755f9ed9: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 02:42:78:da:c4:6d  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br-cd91e6b91600: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 02:42:93:95:fd:32  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br-ebe25881b847: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.19.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.19.255.255
        ether 02:42:f6:dc:b9:fb  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br-ed1db6abbd8c: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.80.1  netmask 255.255.240.0  broadcast 192.168.95.255
        ether 02:42:21:33:6a:29  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br-ee2de731fa5a: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.176.1  netmask 255.255.240.0  broadcast 192.168.191.255
        ether 02:42:c6:59:41:3f  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
        ether 02:42:43:d1:12:75  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

docker_gwbridge: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.16.1  netmask 255.255.240.0  broadcast 192.168.31.255
        ether 02:42:31:9f:59:ad  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eno1: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 80:ce:62:1b:d6:a8  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Bucle local)
        RX packets 50305  bytes 4261755 (4.2 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 50305  bytes 4261755 (4.2 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlo1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.38  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 fe80::141d:fe6e:6a9d:d954  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 88:b1:11:a7:81:7c  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 667177  bytes 529813316 (529.8 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 303992  bytes 86499860 (86.4 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

[EDIT]

In my systemctl list:

```
sys-devices-virtual-net-br\x2d8bec26608e85.device                                        loaded    active   plugged   /sys/devices/virtual/net/br-8bec26608e85                                        
  sys-devices-virtual-net-br\x2d92a88a91f4b0.device                                        loaded    active   plugged   /sys/devices/virtual/net/br-92a88a91f4b0                                        
  sys-devices-virtual-net-br\x2d98b4c7a75e2e.device                                        loaded    active   plugged   /sys/devices/virtual/net/br-98b4c7a75e2e                                        
  sys-devices-virtual-net-br\x2da25c53ab3ce9.device                                        loaded    active   plugged   /sys/devices/virtual/net/br-a25c53ab3ce9                                        
  sys-devices-virtual-net-br\x2db01a537efc09.device                                        loaded    active   plugged   /sys/devices/virtual/net/br-b01a537efc09                                        
  sys-devices-virtual-net-br\x2dbb41b5e452fb.device                                        loaded    active   plugged   /sys/devices/virtual/net/br-bb41b5e452fb                                        
  sys-devices-virtual-net-br\x2dccc1755f9ed9.device                                        loaded    active   plugged   /sys/devices/virtual/net/br-ccc1755f9ed9                                        
  sys-devices-virtual-net-br\x2dcd91e6b91600.device                                        loaded    active   plugged   /sys/devices/virtual/net/br-cd91e6b91600                                        
  sys-devices-virtual-net-br\x2debe25881b847.device                                        loaded    active   plugged   /sys/devices/virtual/net/br-ebe25881b847                                        
  sys-devices-virtual-net-br\x2ded1db6abbd8c.device                                        loaded    active   plugged   /sys/devices/virtual/net/br-ed1db6abbd8c
```

Are they related? I'm a developer, not a networking professional.

Desired State:

[EDIT]

So these networks appears to be docker networks. I'm trying to remove, so one of them seems to overlap something in the network i've got problems. **Working on it...**

DESIRED STATE:

WIFI or LAN working. Remove unused bridge networks.

[EDIT]

/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml

```
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

Comment: Nothing in netplan or systemd?

Comment: cd /etc/netplan/
n$ ls
01-network-manager-all.yaml
$ cat 01-network-manager-all.yaml 
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager

Comment: what do you need about systemd? I'm not a networking professional, i'm a developer. don't know much about networking.

Comment: /etc/networking/interfaces is the old way to configure. The new way is netplan through /etc/netplan/<someconfig>.yaml. Systemd is the networking renderer in between. You'll find its config under /etc/systemd/networkd/<someconfig>.network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very certainly running Docker. This can be infered by a few informations:

- the bridge names look like Docker bridge
- bridges having an IP set use classical Docker bridge IPs: `/16` in the `172.16.0.0/12` space
- you are a developer
- every bridge MAC address start with `02:42`, which designate a private MAC (fine) but if they were truely random they would have many other possibilities. This SO article, related to Docker, talks about it: [How does the Docker assign MAC addresses to containers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42946453/how-does-the-docker-assign-mac-addresses-to-containers). The official link there doesn't exist anymore.
- running a search on the Docker documentation site: https://docs.docker.com/search/?q=02%3A42 shows so many examples with this MAC peculiarity it can't be something else (sadly I didn't find the original link about MAC addresses).

With all those trails, I can fairly safely assume that your issues are caused from running several Docker networks which interefere with your usual network routing. Just change their settings to not interfere anymore. This should probably be done as a separate question (I wouldn't know if SO or here is best suited). This should be related to [`docker network`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network/) and its sub-commands.

This question might help: https://forums.docker.com/t/dtr-network-overlaps-corporate-lan/22193

Comment: I'm removing docker networks with `docker network ls -q | xargs docker network rm`. Tomorrow I'll be in a problematic network and i'll try to connect. I'll get you the feedback tomorrow.

Comment: Everything seems you're right about docker lan overlapping... Give me 24hrs to confirm it to you.

Comment: Everything working. You were right about your diagnosis.